# Deploying webservice with gSOAP and Apache

Tags: c++, apache, gsoap

I'd like to know what is Apache and mod_gsoap behavior on handling the session and function call from gSOAP webservice library (the code written by developer / business logic). Does the Apache/mod_gsoap create one new instance of gSoap webservice library for each soap call ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module `mod_gsoap` library is loaded into Apache HTTP Server at runtime via the Dynamic Shared Object (DSO) mechanism. For each inbound XML/SOAP service call that is handled by `mod_gsoap`, the module's handler creates a local gsoap engine `struct soap` context to process the XML request and return the XML response by marshalling your service operation parameters and return structures in XML. The context and all if its dynamic allocations are released when the handler is finished. See `gsoap_handler` in gsoap/mod_gsoap/mod_gsoap-0.9/apache_20/mod_gsoap.c and the [Apache mod_gsoap documentation](http://www.genivia.com/doc/apache/html/index.html).